# List of objects to JSON to Html Table?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, html-table

If I have a list of objects

```
IEnumerable<MyType> myTypes;
```

Is it possible for me to return this to the client as JSON

```
return Json(myTypes);
```

and if so, is it possible for me to convert this (now JSON format) list to a `<table>` when it gets to the client?

Is there any jQuery plugin to do this?

The thing is, there's loads of other stuff I need to send as JSON also, so generating a table with a PartialView and embedding that into the JSON is a extra complexity that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with my own solution for a similar problem, I wanted to be able to display any JSON object array response into a nice table without having to hard code anything in the JavaScript so it was reusable!

Here is what I did...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "DemoSvc.asmx/GetJSONTableContents",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",
            success: function(res) {
                $('#<%= DynamicGridLoading.ClientID %>').hide();
                $('#<%= DynamicGrid.ClientID %>').append(CreateDynamicTable(res.d)).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is doing the pulling of data from the web service to the page, the important part of this code is the call to the "CreateDynamicTable()" that converts the JSON object array to a pretty HTML table.  Below is the code, the output is a pretty table of HTML.

```
function CreateDynamicTable(objArray) {
  var array = JSON.parse(objArray);

  var str = '<table class="lightPro">';
  str += '<tr>';
  for (var index in array[0]) {
    str += '<th scope="col">' + index + '</th>';
  }
  str += '</tr>';
  str += '<tbody>';
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    str += (i % 2 == 0) ? '<tr class="alt">' : '<tr>';
    for (var index in array[i]) {
      str += '<td>' + array[i][index] + '</td>';
    }
    str += '</tr>';
  }
  str += '</tbody>'
  str += '</table>';
  return str;
}
```

I also looked for something FREE to do this, but everything I found was commercial or required hard coding column values.  I did a quick blog post with additional details, screen shot and a simple VS 2008 demo.  Overall, it's working perfect for what I needed.

[Blog Article on JSON data to HTML Table](http://www.zachhunter.net/2010/04/json-objects-to-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an HTML table, exactly, but I use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) along with Craig Stuntz's [helper functions](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/15/38212/) to "export" any `IQueryable<T>` as JSON.  The helper function `ToJqGridData` sends JSON in exactly the format required by jqGrid, so your code is nice and neat:

```
MyObjectRepository rep = new MyObjectRepository();
var myObjects = from o in rep.SelectAll()
                select new 
                {
                    Prop1 = o.Prop1,
                    Prop2 = o.Prop2
                    ...
                }
return Json(apps.ToJqGridData(page, rows, sidx, null, null), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Be aware you'll also need to update the global settings for your jqGrids to make them compatible with the naming conventions used by `ToJqGridData` (I just include this script in my master page):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    GridDemo.SiteMaster.setDefaults();
});

var GridDemo = {
    Home: {
        GridDemo: {}
    },
    SiteMaster: {
        setDefaults: function() {
            $.jgrid.defaults = $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
                datatype: 'json',
                height: 'auto',
                imgpath: '/Scripts/jqGrid/themes/lightness/images',
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "Rows",
                    page: "Page",
                    total: "Total",
                    records: "Records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    userdata: "UserData",
                    id: "Id"
                },
                loadui: "block",
                mtype: 'GET',
                multiboxonly: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                rowList: [10, 20, 50],
                viewrecords: true
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @Dave, thanks but jqGrid's gone Commercial.. that kind of rules it out for me.

Comment: Well crap, missed that entirely.  Does this mean there is absolutely no decent open-source grid?

Comment: yeah, & it's only since recently too. I don't know about any other open source grids though. Hopefully since jqGrid's gone corporate a new one will get started.